# Clear Input textbox fields after select box selected index has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clear the current values of `Input` fields `totalA` and `qtyA` when the selected value of a `select` box, `acct` has been changed.

I have this code so far, but am unsure where to clear the values.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#acct").on('change', function() {
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        if (selVal == 'Full-Time') { // Full Time
            $('.parttime').hide();
            $('.fulltime').show();
            $('.agent').show();
            $('.error').hide();
        }
        else if (selVal == 'Part-Time') { // Part Time
            $('.parttime').show();
            $('.fulltime').hide();
            $('.agent').show();
            $('.error').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.parttime').hide();
            $('.fulltime').hide();
            $('.agent').hide();
            $('.error').show();
        }
    });

    $('#qtyA').on('change', function() {
        var selVal = $("#acct").val();
        if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
            var total = 0;
            if (selVal == 'Full-Time') {
                total = parseInt($(this).val()) * 1280;
            }
            else if (selVal == 'Part-Time') {
                total = parseInt($(this).val()) * 720;
            }
            $('#totalA').val(total.toFixed(2));
        }
        else {
            $(this).val('0');
             $('#totalA').val('0.00');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The `select` box code:

```
<p>
   <label for="acct" style="margin-right:45px;"><strong />Account Type<strong><font color="red" size="3"> * </font></strong></label>
   <select name="acct" style="background-color:white;"  id="acct" value="" class="validate[custom[cname]] text-input">
      <option value="Full-Time">Full-Time</option>
      <option value="Part-Time">Part-Time</option>
      <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
   </select>
</p>
```

The `Input` fields:

```
<p>
<table class="agent">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <lable style="margin-right:89px;"># of Agent(s)<font color="red" size="3"> * </font></lable>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input style="width:25px; margin-left:5px;" type="text" name="qtyA" id="qtyA" />
        </td>
        <td>
            X  &nbsp; $<label id="acctFull Time" class="desc fulltime" style="display:none">1280</label>
            <label id="acctPart Time" class="desc parttime" style="display:none">720</label> = &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            $<input style="width:65px; margin-left:5px;" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="totalA" id="totalA" onchange="calculate()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</p>
<p class="error" align="center">Please select an Account Type.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I did get you right... You'd like to **reset values** in `#totalA` and `#qtyA` **onChange** of `#acct`? In case I am right you may try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#acct").on('change', function() {
    resetValues();

    var selVal = $(this).val();
    if (selVal == 'Full-Time') { // Full Time
        $('.parttime').hide();
        $('.fulltime').show();
        $('.agent').show();
        $('.error').hide();
    }
    else if (selVal == 'Part-Time') { // Part Time
        $('.parttime').show();
        $('.fulltime').hide();
        $('.agent').show();
        $('.error').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.parttime').hide();
        $('.fulltime').hide();
        $('.agent').hide();
        $('.error').show();
    }
  });

  $('#qtyA').on('change', function() {
    var selVal = $("#acct").val();
    if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
        var total = 0;
        if (selVal == 'Full-Time') {
            total = parseInt($(this).val()) * 1280;
        }
        else if (selVal == 'Part-Time') {
            total = parseInt($(this).val()) * 720;
        }
        $('#totalA').val(total.toFixed(2));
    }
    else {
        resetValues();
    }
  });

  function resetValues()
  {
     $('#qtyA').val('0'); // or set empty
     $('#totalA').val('0.00');   // or set empty
  }
});
```

As you **did reset values on entering an invalid value** within `#qtyA` I *created a function* and just **added a call** to it on start of *change​ eventHandler*

Comment: didn't work your idea is correct but script didn't work when implemented.

Comment: See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbUmv/) with my **scriptCode**. Worked for me! _Pls respond if it worked for you too_

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#acct").on('change', function() {
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        if (selVal == 'Full-Time') { // Full Time
        $('#qtyA').val('0'); // or set empty
            $('#totalA').val('0.00');   // or set empty
            $('.parttime').hide();
            $('.fulltime').show();
            $('.agent').show();
            $('.error').hide();
        }
        else if (selVal == 'Part-Time') { // Part Time
        $('#qtyA').val('0'); // or set empty
            $('#totalA').val('0.00');   // or set empty
            $('.parttime').show();
            $('.fulltime').hide();
            $('.agent').show();
            $('.error').hide();
        }
        else {
        $('#qtyA').val('0'); // or set empty
            $('#totalA').val('0.00');   // or set empty
            $('.parttime').hide();
            $('.fulltime').hide();
            $('.agent').hide();
            $('.error').show();
        }
    });
```

instead of putting it on the onchange function
i added the script in the ready function so it changes when 
the user selects along with the div